# Proof of reduced upper-tail inequality for standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics, inequality, probability-distributions, faq

X∼N(0,1), then to prove that for x>0, 
$$ P(X>x)≤ \frac{1}{2}exp(−x^2/2) $$
I know how to prove the other two kinds of upper-tail inequality for standard normal distribution like this one
$$exp(−x^2/2) $$
and this one
$$ \frac{exp(−x^2/2)}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}  $$
But have no idea how to do this reduced upper-tail inequality. Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: How do you get the first bound?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy The first bound, exp(-x^2/2), could be obtained by Chernoff bound using moment generating function of standard normal distribution.